# Why does aqua microscanner fail in my Jenkinsfile?

Tags: security, jenkins-pipeline, dockerfile

I am trying to scan a Docker image that I am building in my Jenkins pipeline. I have installed the Aqua Security microscanner plugin, and have a valid token. However I am getting this error:

`Error response from daemon: Dockerfile parse error line 1: FROM requires either one or three arguments
Sending build context to Docker daemon  23.93MB`

my Jenkinsfile snippet:

```
...
stage('Container Scan') {
  aquaMicroscanner imageName: '', notCompliesCmd: 'exit 1', onDisallowed: 'fail'
}
...
```

my Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM golang:alpine AS build-env
WORKDIR /go/src
COPY . /go/src/test-app
RUN cd /go/src/test-app && go build .
#go build command creates a linux binary that can run without any 
go tooling.

FROM alpine
RUN apk update && apk add ca-certificates && rm -rf /var/cache/apk*
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /go/src/test-app/test-app /app
COPY --from=build-env /go/src/test-app/templates /app/templates
COPY --from=build-env /go/src/test-app/static /app/static

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT [ "./test-app" ]
```

Both of my `FROM` statements have either 1 or 3 arguments, so I am puzzled about the error message.

Comment: Your Docker install is probably too old to support what you are doing.

Comment: That was a great guess, but unfortunately my docker install is up to date... `Docker version 18.09.3, build 774a1f4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my own issue... apparently Aqua microscanner requires an image name, which I somehow managed to omit.

```
aquaMicroscanner imageName: '', notCompliesCmd: 'exit 1', onDisallowed: 'fail'
```